# How to parse a simple array with Gson that contains mixed types?

Tags: gson

```
*{
    "data":["v",
        {
            "value1":6,
            "value2":0,
            "value3":1
        }
    ]
}*
```

How to parse a simple array with Gson that contains mixed types?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to parse into a JsonElement:

```
JsonElement parsed = new JsonParser().parse(json);
```

You can use [JsonElement's APIs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) to interrogate the parsed object as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(jsonInputStr, JsonElement.class);
JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
```